# How to get relationships between two tables when ids are hashed in model accessor?

Tags: php, laravel, model, relationship, hashids

The relationship between two tables work correctly but when I use `Hashids` it doesn't and it returns null.

My code:

Car Model:

```
public function getCarIdAttribute($value)
{
    return Hashids::encode($value);
}
```

Car Image Model:

```
public function getCarIdAttribute($value)
{
    return Hashids::encode($value);
}
```

Reserve Car Model:

```
public function getCarIdAttribute($value)
{
    return Hashids::encode($value);
}

public function getReserveIdAttribute($value)
{
    return Hashids::encode($value);
}

public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CarImage::class, 'car_id');
}
```

My Controller:

`$cars = Car::with('images')->get();`

`$cars` has value but images inside it, not!

Note that it is working with plain ids but when I hash their ids it doesn't return any value!

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. Since you are hashing the `id` attributes by using [Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor), any call to a property such as

```
$car->car_id; // would return the hashed id
```

Obviously, since the Eloquent relationship depends on the actual id value and not the hashed one, the relationships would break. That's why it's a bad idea to have an accessor for your primary/foreign key.